# Equivalent properties of Fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

I have Theorem, which states: Let $\mathcal{H}$ be Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\mathcal{\varepsilon}=\{ e_i\}_1^{\infty}$ The following properties are equivalent:

1) $\epsilon$ is complet orthnormal basis for $\mathcal{H}$.

2) For ewery $x, y \in \mathcal{H}$:
$$
\langle\,x,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle\,x,e_i\rangle \overline{\langle\,y,e_i\rangle}
$$
3) Parseval's equality: For ewery $x \in \mathcal{H}$:
$$
||x||^2=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\langle\,x,e_i\rangle|^2
$$
How to prove that this 3 statements are equivalent?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I actually dont have an idea, how to start... I mean, I could prove $1\rightarrow 2$ with linearity in first, and conjugate-linearity of second parameter of inner product ? But how do I start to prove connection with Parseval's equality?

Comment: Hint: You just need to use the definition of a complete orthonormal basis.